# Python - Pyg Latin?

Tags: python

I am trying to expand on the Codecademy pig latin convertor so that it accepts sentences rather than just single words and converts each word in the sentence. Here's the code that I have:

```
pyg = 'ay'

pyg_input = raw_input("Please enter a sentence: ")
print

if len(pyg_input) > 0 and pyg_input.isalpha():
    lwr_input = pyg_input.lower()
    lst = lwr_input.split()
    for item in lst:
        frst = lst[item][0]
        if frst == 'a' or frst == 'e' or frst == 'i' or frst == 'o' or frst == 'u':
            lst[item] = lst[item] + pyg
        else:
            lst[item] = lst[item][1:len(lst[item]) + frst + pyg
    print ' '.join(lst)
```

I'm not sure what is wrong so I am grateful of any help.
Thanks

Comment: You don't say what your problem is!

Comment: Try `'foo'.isalpha()` and then `'foo bar'.isalpha()` in the interpreter.  The result may be enlightening.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, that's why.

Comment: @torek Ah, thanks! It is still not working so there must be something wrong with the rest of the code aswell

Comment: Yes, but at least now you're getting stack dumps. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Sentence can contain non-alphabet (for example space): so pyg_input.isalpha() will yield False:
- You're using `lst[item]` to access each character. Instead use `item`.
- You cannot update list while you iterate the list. In the following code I used another list called `latin`.
- Your code have a SyntaxError in following line (no closing braket):

  ```
  lst[item][1:len(lst[item])
  ```
- The following code is not perfect. For example, you need to filter out non-alphabet such as `,`, `.`, ...

---

```
pyg = 'ay'

pyg_input = raw_input("Please enter a sentence: ")
print

if len(pyg_input) > 0:# and pyg_input.isalpha():
    lwr_input = pyg_input.lower()
    lst = lwr_input.split()
    latin = []
    for item in lst:
        frst = item[0]
        if frst in 'aeiou':
            item = item + pyg
        else:
            item = item[1:] + frst + pyg
        latin.append(item)
    print ' '.join(latin)
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error on 'latin.append(item)' when I try this

Comment: Its fine, that seemed to be the codecademy labs. I ran it from a text editor and it was fine. Thanks!

Comment: @falsetrue I know it's not perfect, but I am new to python so I was just experimenting, seeing if I could do it. Filtering non-alphabetic characters will be my next task :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below way to implement the pyg_latin translator

```
import enchant
input_str = raw_input("Enter a word:")
d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
d.check(input_str)
pyg_latin = input_str[1:]+input_str[0]+"ay"
print pyg_latin
```